# multiply the numbers entered by user and when the user types 'x' for example to print the sum of the numbers enter by that moment

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace While_product
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string firstInput = Console.ReadLine();
            int sum1 = 0;

            if (firstInput == "x")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(1);
            }

            else

                while (firstInput != "x")
                {


                    int number = Convert.ToInt32(firstInput);
                    sum1 *= number;
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
for exampe:
5
4
3
x
output: 60
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This looks like homework to me. We will not do your homework for you. If you have an specific question, we´re glad to help you. Please tell us, where are you stuck. (see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: You need to initialise `sum1` as 1 - if it's zero, then `sum1 *= number` will always be zero.

Comment: You also need to actually update `firstInput`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]As per I understood you have to multiply the records which you have entered before x, here we go.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;

  namespace Print
 {
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int y = 0;

        string firstInput = Console.ReadLine();
        List<string> strArray = new List<string>();
        int multiplication = 1;

        strArray.Add(firstInput);

        if (firstInput == "x")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(multiplication);
        }

        else
        {
            while (y == 0)
            {
                multiplication = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (strArray[i] != "x")
                    {
                        int number = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[i]);
                        multiplication *= number;
                        firstInput = Console.ReadLine();
                        strArray.Add(firstInput);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        y = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(multiplication);
    }
}
 }
```